# curl issue in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: curl

curl: symbol lookup error: curl: undefined symbol: curl_url_set, version CURL_OPENSSL_4

manish@manish-Latitude-3420:~$ sudo apt-get install curl

The following NEW packages will be installed:
curl
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgra
manish@manish-Latitude-3420:~$

manish@manish-Latitude-3420:~$ curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -

curl: symbol lookup error: curl: undefined symbol: curl_url_set, version CURL_OPENSSL_4
manish@manish-Latitude-3420:~$
manish@manish-Latitude-3420:~$ curl_url_set -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -
curl_url_set: command not found

Answer (score 0):

I tried with curl & it did not help. still curl issue which I will solve on some other time.

But this helped me
https://askubuntu.com/a/1054720
git clone https://github.com/curl/curl.git
cd curl
./buildconf    (try with sudo, if....)
./configure    (same)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QRoj.png)
make
make test # optional
sudo make install

make sure while creating file/folder, use with sudo command where ever it r

Answer (score 0):

I tried using above... It worked out

It was a great help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).